# LINQ question in .NET 6 / EF Core conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I currently have a .NET 4 Web API using Entity Framework 3 that I'm  upgrading to .NET 6 / EF Core. I currently have a LINQ query that  looks like this (and works fine):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResults> GetCars()
{
    var x = from f in _context.CarMakes
            group c in f.Make into m
            select new { c.Key };

    return Json(new 
                {   
                    data = await x.ToListAsync()
                };
}
```

This returns the following data:

```
Chevy
Ford
Volvo
Toyota
```

and so on.

I'm trying to use this same query in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that is using EF Core, but it fails, and throws an error.

In the .NET 6 / EF Core project, I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResults<IEnumerable<CarMakes>>>> GetCars()
{
    var x = from f in _context.CarMakes
            group c in f.Make into m
            select new { c.Key };

    return await x.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get an error message of:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Threading.Task.Task<System.Collections.GenericList

Comment: ````[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<CarMakes>> GetCars()
{
   var x = from f in _context.CarMakes
   group c in f.Make into m
   select new { c.Key };

return await x.ToListAsync();
}````

Answer (score 0):

Don't return an ActionResult, just return the IEnumerable.

Comment: I tried that as well and it kicks me back another error : [ cannot return a value from an iterator.  Use the yield statement to return ]

Answer (score 0):

I got this working

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResults<IEnumerable<CarMakes>>>> GetCars()
{
   var x = from f in _context.CarMakes
   group c in f.Make into m
   select new { c.Key };

  return Ok(await x.ToListAsync());

}
```

not 100% sure adding OK() gave me results, but it works for now.